# undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-2.6

I have this little code:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import signal, misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path="~/pics/"
band_1 = misc.imread(path + "foo.tif");

H = array((1/2.0, 1/4.0, 1/2.0));
signal.convolve2d(band_1.flatten(), H)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(band_1)
plt.show()
```

then I execute this code `python foo.py` and it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy import signal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from filter_design import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scipy import special, optimize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from nonlin import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/nonlin.py", line 113, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import norm, solve, inv, qr, svd, lstsq, LinAlgError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from basic import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from lapack import get_lapack_funcs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/lapack.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import clapack
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so: undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv
```

What is wrong? It seems to be `from scipy import signal` but I do not know clearly.

I have check another sources and forums but there is no reasons yet:

- http://old.nabble.com/scipy.interpolate-imports---%3E-lapack-errors-td30343730.html
- http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/27290

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

On Debian, you can use `update-alternatives`, assuming you have more than reference implementation installed.

From [debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/LinearAlgebraLibraries)

```
update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3
```

Comment: This did it for me. Details at http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/12/19/libblas-and-liblapack-issues-and-speed,-with-scipy-and-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm the only person who did.

Comment: @Emre Sorry, never mind then. I was confused by the gap between the +1 and comment.

Answer (score 3):

I can't be certain since you didn't specify what distribution you're using, but I ran into the same issue on Gentoo.

/usr/lib and /usr/lib64 have symlinks to the actual libraries.  By default, it links to the reference implementation of libblas, libcblas, and liblapack -- which doesn't export symbols for clapack_sgesv, and many other routines.

To resolve this in Gentoo:

```
sudo emerge blas-atlas
eselect blas list
eselect cblas list
sudo eselect blas set X # Grab X from the result of
sudo eselect cblas set X # the 'list' lines above
sudo emerge lapack-atlas
eselect lapack list
sudo eselect lapack set X
sudo emerge --unmerge scipy numpy matplotlib
sudo emerge scipy numpy matplotlib (... whatever else ...)
```

Comment: ... as an aside, where the option is available you'll wanna use the threaded one.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem after an upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. The problem was that I had two versions of scipy installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. To fix the problem I did:

```
 sudo apt-get remove python-scipy
 sudo rm -fr /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy*
 sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```