# clapack.so: undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv on RHEL

Tags: scipy

I'm getting this error when importing scipy.stats:

```
import scipy.stats
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 322, in <module>
from stats import *
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 194, in <module>
import scipy.linalg as linalg
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
from basic import *
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 12, in <module>
from lapack import get_lapack_funcs
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/lapack.py", line 15, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import clapack
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so: undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv
```

Looks like clapack.so links to the full, ATLAS version of libatlas:

```
ldd /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff232e6000)
liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007f23b8ad7000)
libptf77blas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libptf77blas.so.3 (0x00007f23b88b7000)
libptcblas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libptcblas.so.3 (0x00007f23b8697000)
libatlas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.so.3 (0x00007f23b8120000)
libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00007f23b7d65000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f23b7a73000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f23b77da000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f23b75c3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f23b7232000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f23b6fdb000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f23b6dbd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f23b6bb9000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f23b69b6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000032a2200000)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823692/undefined-symbol-clapack-sgesv)