# Error importing SciPy on Ubuntu 12.10: clapack_sgesv

Tags: python, scipy

I'm starting to work with Python and I've been trying to use some methods of SciPy and SciKits, but when I import the SciPy module I get this error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so: 
   undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv
```

I've been looking for a solution but haven't found one yet. This is on Ubuntu 12.10. Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined symbol: clapack\_sgesv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823692/undefined-symbol-clapack-sgesv)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but it sounds as though you're missing Linear Algebra routines, which are pretty heavily used by SciPy. Does this page help? http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/BuildingGeneral

There also seem to be Lapack/BLAS routines available through apt-get http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html

Answer (score 0):

[This bug report](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1031) has some suggestions. Taking into account [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823692/undefined-symbol-clapack-sgesv) similar question (which links to [this](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/LinearAlgebraLibraries) Debian wiki article) you will probably need to switch your system liblapack to the one providing required symbols (such as the one from `libatlas3-base`).