# clapack import error (from Scipy)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I'm having problems with the importation of some libraries from Scipy. I got this error.

```
>>> from scipy import interpolate
 in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import clapack
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so: undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv
```

I believe that it could be happen because I have some libraries installed in /usr/lib and anothers in /usr/local/lib and it seems that they are not linked. I have tried to do it with LD_PATH and also changing /etc/ld.so.config but nothing works.

If I type ldd command (for clapack.so), I got this:

```
ldd -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0xb6f71000)
        liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 (0xb68ff000)
        libatlas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libatlas.so.3 (0xb663b000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgfortran.so.3 (0xb6593000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6522000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb64fa000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb63c6000)
        libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0xb60d1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb60b2000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fae000)
undefined symbol: PyExc_ImportError     (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_ValueError      (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_TypeError       (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyComplex_Type        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_RuntimeError    (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyType_Type   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: _Py_NoneStruct        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_AttributeError  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dgesv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_cgesv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_zgesv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_sposv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dposv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_cposv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_zposv (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_spotrf        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dpotrf        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_cpotrf        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_zpotrf        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_spotrs        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dpotrs        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_cpotrs        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_zpotrs        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_spotri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dpotri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_cpotri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_zpotri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_slauum        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dlauum        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_clauum        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_zlauum        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_strtri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_dtrtri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_ctrtri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: clapack_ztrtri        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyDict_SetItemString  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyString_AsString     (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyMem_Free    (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_NoMemory        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: _PyObject_New (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyOS_snprintf (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyString_FromStringAndSize    (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: Py_FindMethod (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Format  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Occurred        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyString_FromString   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyString_FromFormat   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyModule_GetDict      (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PySequence_GetItem    (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyCObject_AsVoidPtr   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyType_IsSubtype      (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PySequence_Check      (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: Py_BuildValue (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_GetAttrString        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_NewException    (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyDict_GetItemString  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Print   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyString_ConcatAndDel (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyDict_DelItemString  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4        (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyImport_ImportModule (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Clear   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_SetString       (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyNumber_Int  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyMem_Malloc  (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
undefined symbol: PyDict_New    (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/clapack.so)
```

I have tried to install diferent versions of SciPy but neither this way fixes the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined symbol: clapack\_sgesv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823692/undefined-symbol-clapack-sgesv)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have fixed the problem with this commands obtained from ldd other question ([undefined symbol: clapack_sgesv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823692/undefined-symbol-clapack-sgesv))

```
update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3
```

I just needed to change the default configuration of liblapack.so.3 and it works.